# Spatial Clustering Coefficient using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial, spatial

I have a dataset of categorical points and their location (coordinates). I wanted to know if there is any way of calculating spatial clustering coefficients for each category using R.

My data looks like this:

```
    ID  LON LAT TYPE
    1   8.43    12.24   SHOES
    2   8.44    12.32   CONVENIENCE
    3   8.42    12.27   CONVENIENCE
    4   8.41    12.26   SHOES
    5   8.43    12.24   SHOES
```

The idea is to compare how clustered is each category (`TYPE`), so I would need a specific number for each category and then rank them from "more clustered" to "less clustered". The objective is answering which `TYPE` (shoes or convenience) is more clustered and to what extent (with a quantitative value). Ideally, the output would look something like this:

```
SHOES clustering coefficient: 0.86
CONVENIENCE clustering coefficient: 0.32
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your dataset?

Comment: Are you looking for Moran's I?
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-calculate-morans-i-in-r/

Comment: @AndrewBrēza I am not really sure since I am not very familiar with Moran's I. As far as I know, it is a measure of spatial autocorrelation, but is it the same as "clustering coefficient"? I mean, does it measure how much "close" points are?